# PHP ternary returning wrong

Tags: php, mysqli, ternary-operator

Alright so I am a bit confused, this method I am using to check if someone is already registered or not aint working.

```
private function isRegistered($username) {
    $sql = $this->connect();

    $sql->real_escape_string($username);

    $res = $sql->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

    $rows = $res->num_rows;

    $sql->close();

    return ($rows >= 1) ? true : false;
}
```

For some people it returns true and for some false. I mean if they enter a name that is NOT inside the database sometimes it will return true eventho it doesn't exist.

And they way I check it is simple

```
public function register($username, $pass, $email) {
    if(!$this->isRegistered($username)) {
        $sql = $this->connect();

        $sql->real_escape_string($username);
        $sql->real_escape_string($email);
        $password = hash('sha512', $pass);

        $sql->real_escape_string($password);

        $sql->query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')");

        $sql->close();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the execution itself is this

```
$reg = $user->register($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']);

if($reg == true) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "acc_exists";
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `$username = $sql->real_escape_string($username);`? and so on.

Comment: What different would it make on the returning value?

Comment: Well you're not actually escaping it. It's producing an escaped string but you aren't overwriting $username with it. If their username invalidates your SQL you won't get expected results. On the same note, are you trimming input before/after, changing case before and after or anything that will make matching the username more difficult?

Comment: `$sql->real_escape_string($username)` doesn't modify `$username`. It returns a value (the escaped string) that you ignore. This statement is useless unless you use the value it returns.

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is with the ternary operator? Have you debugged the `$res->num_rows;` response? BTW, in your return you can simple do: `return ($rows >= 1);`. That will return the according boolean.

Comment: Alright I get it now regarding the $sql->real_escape_string, I will fix it. 

@nikoskip well yeah, I mean for some reason it glitches out, I am not quite sure why tho. I went as far as debugging it and I was right about it, sometimes it returned correct data sometimes it didnt